# Getting two defining points for almost rectangular objects

Tags: python

I have a large number of objects that represents windows and doors in a building. These objects are almost rectangular and vertical and I now need to find two representing points for each of these objects, one lower corner and one opposite upper corner. The idea I have is

1. Create a bounding box around each selected object
2. Create a vertical plane in the midpoint of each box
3. Find the two vertexes with the largest distance for each plane.

This works kind of fine but it is crazy slow when I have a few hundred objects so I wonder if somebody could find me a better method.
[image]

The code I use for step 1 is

```
    selected = bpy.context.selected_objects
    for obj in selected:
        #ensure origin is centered on bounding box center
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='BOUNDS')
        #create a cube for the bounding box
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        #our new cube is now the active object, so we can keep track of it in a variable:
        bound_box = bpy.context.active_object
        #copy transforms
        bound_box.dimensions = obj.dimensions
        bound_box.location = obj.location
        bound_box.rotation_euler = obj.rotation_euler
```

For step 2 I use

```
selected = bpy.context.selected_objects
            for obj in selected:
                if obj.type=='MESH':
                    o = bpy.ops.object
                    m = bpy.ops.mesh
                    box = obj
                    box.select_set(True)
                    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = box
                    o.duplicate()
                    # plane at following line is actually the duplicated box
                    plane = bpy.context.active_object
                    faces = plane.data.polygons
                    # select all faces
                    o.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
                    m.select_mode(type='FACE')
                    m.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
                    o.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
                    (x, y, z) = box.scale
                    # deselect the face you want to keep by largest area, xy = 0th face, xz = 1st face, yz = 2nd face
                    areas = [x*y, x*z, y*z]
                    faces[areas.index(max(areas))].select = False
                    # delete unwanted faces and set geometry to origin
                    o.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
                    m.delete(type='FACE')
                    o.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
                    o.origin_set(type='GEOMETRY_ORIGIN', center='MEDIAN')
                    #box.select_set(True)
                    # give plane similar name
                    plane.name = box.name + '_Window'
                    objs = bpy.data.objects
                    objs.remove(box, do_unlink=True)
            #Delete stray empty meshes. not sure why these are created
            scene = bpy.context.scene
            empty_meshobs = [o for o in scene.objects
                if o.type == 'MESH'
                and not o.data.vertices]
            while empty_meshobs:
                bpy.data.objects.remove(empty_meshobs.pop())
```

Step 3 I have not figured out yet.

Comment: Hello, the computations should be pretty straightfoward so I'm sure your script can be optimized. Could you add it to your question ? Cheers

Comment: Absolutely. the second step is very slow.